# the efficient and accurate way of parsing a web html to text field with formating?

Tags: apache-flex, parsing, text

i want to parse the web html to flex text field i have three approaches in mind to do soo

1. to use string function splice etc. to replace tags with the one which text fields can understand but is it too complex and processing over head is there that reduces the efficiency but i have max control to do changes what i needed.
2. parsing the html to xml and then use this as the text input to text field what about the efficiency and control need to know about from this question.
3. regular expressions .

which one will be the most suitable in paring the web text.

help required

regards.

Comment: there are very few options to convert the html tags to uitextfield understandable tags is there any suitable way to attain the text formatting very close to the html displayed text

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to completely change your approach. If you need a simple HTML to be displayed, then you can directly parse it by the flash/flex. In other cases, when you have a complex HTML page(s), then you should use IFrame. That's really simple and efficient approach and could be very useful in your case. Here you can find its description:
 [Flex and Iframe](http://flex-blogger.com/blog/2010/12/11/flex-and-html-embedded-in-iframe/),[Flex Iframe Project site](http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/).

Good luck!

Comment: it is necessary to parse html for html text of uitextfield of flex i can't use any other component

Comment: Ok, I see. In my opinion you could just use the replace function to less and regular expr to more complex content, in order to translate the original HTML code to the subset that Flash/Flex understands. I think parsing a whole document could be really time-consuming when used with huge, complex HTML code. You need to decide what is better in your particular case. Another option is to translate a HTML document on your server side, so that Flash/Flex gets a content that is ready to display.